# snowflake take only required field in json data field if it is available

Tags: json, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table like below

emp_data:

| id | emp_name | social_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shiva | [{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"999888777", "status":"active"}}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"999888777", "chat":"how are you"}}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"999888777", "chat":"I am Good"}}}] |
| 2 | kiran | [{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"111222333", "status":"active"}}}] |
| 3 | mohan | [{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}},{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}}] |
| 4 | hari |  |

I am trying to get customer_id when available like below from eixsting social_field json data

| id | emp_name | social_field | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shiva | [{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"999888777", "status":"active"}}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"999888777", "chat":"how are you"}}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"999888777", "chat":"I am Good"}}}] | 999888777 |
| 2 | kiran | [{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}},{"custinfo":{"custinfo":{"customer_id":"111222333", "status":"active"}}}] | 111222333 |
| 3 | mohan | [{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}},{"social_media":{"facebook":"user_name","twitter":"twitteR_name"}}] | 0 |
| 4 | hari |  | 0 |

I am trying below query using REGEXP_SUBSTR, but getting null in customer_id field

```
select *,REGEXP_SUBSTR(social_field, '("customer_id":"([^"]+)")', 1, 1, 'e', 2)  as cust_id
from emp_data;
```

and

```
SELECT
  id,
  emp_name,
  social_field,
  COALESCE(JSON_VALUE(social_field, '$[1].custinfo.custinfo.customer_id'), '0') AS customer_id
FROM
  your_table
```

Any help in adjusting REGEXP_SUBSTR to get desired value.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `flatten`, and since there are multiple customer_id per emp_name, we can use `group by` and `max()` to extract only one :

```
select e.*, coalesce(s.customer_id, 0) as customer_id
from emp_data e
left join (
  select t.id, max(a.value:custinfo:custinfo:customer_id::varchar) as customer_id
  from emp_data t
  , lateral flatten(input => parse_json(t.social_field)) a
  group by t.id
) as s on s.id = e.id;
```

Comment: Can we do this using regex because id is not unique filed for me.

Comment: You can group by any unique column/combination of columns